# Do I have to register iOS device in Apple Developer Programm?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I made my app `Registered Apple Developer` account and paid 99$

Now I want to publish my App.

But Xcode says:

> "**Unable to create a provisioning profile because your team has no
>   devices registered in the Member Center. Please connect a device,
>   enable it for development, and add it to the Member Center using the
>   Organizer.**".

Do I have to buy iPhone to publish my app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have to register each device UDID on which you want to test your application before submitting.

For testing (development)you need a real device.

You should add provisioning profile and Distribution Certificate before distribution.

Also Validate your application.

Note : it's better for developpement to test your application before submitting to AppStore.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Testing app must needed before submitting to App Store. event thought 
You can create `"Distribution provisional profile"` to publish app. its not required to add device id.

[SubmittingYourApp to app store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)